# Задание по ООП python

Tags: python, ооп

Необходимо напиcать класс MarchCat, который при вызове метода meowing  будет попеременно выводить "meow" или "woof".

```
 Sample Input 1:

cat1 = MarchCat()
cat1.meowing()
cat1.meowing()
cat1.meowing()
cat1.meowing()
cat1.meowing()
cat1.meowing()

Sample Output 1:

meow
woof
meow
woof
meow
woof
```

Comment: За вас никто не напишет. Пытайтесь.

Comment: Менять переменную нужно внутри метода `meowing`. И там же проверять и выводить либо то либо это. Это можно разными способами сделать, подумайте.

Answer (score 5):

Реализовал таким образом!!!

```
class MarchCat:
    numInstances = 0
    def meowing(self):
        self.numInstances += 1
        if self.numInstances % 2 == 0:
            print("woof")
        else:
            print("meow")
```

Comment: Ну вот, всё получилось. Главное начать )

Answer (score 2):

```py
class MarchCat:
    def __init__(self):
        from itertools import cycle
        self._mm = cycle(['meow', 'woof'])

    def meowing(self):
        print(next(self._mm))

cat1 = MarchCat()
```

Comment: Вы использовали импорт внутри класса, хотя как мне известно импорты должны быть в начале файла, можете объяснить почему вы так делаете?

Comment: @Александр, чтобы не разводить зоопарк импортированных модулей, если можно этого не делать. В данном случае код создает только один экземпляр класса и более не предусмотрено, посему вааще пофиг. Но вот если мы создадим cat2 то станет не пофиг, поскольку импорт произойдет повторно при инициализации нового экземпляра. Такой импорт целесообразно использовать в основном при обработке маловероятных событий (к примеру исключений)

Comment: Спасибо.......!